# At which hop is my package discarded?

Tags: networking, tcp, traceroute

Here's traceroute output on my server:

```
# traceroute -e 220.181.112.244
traceroute to 220.181.112.244 (220.181.112.244), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.200.6.254 (10.200.6.254)  1.954 ms  2.044 ms  1.776 ms
 2  192.168.203.1 (192.168.203.1)  1.421 ms  1.506 ms  1.339 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
```

Does this mean `192.168.203.1` discard my package? Or `192.168.203.1` can't reach another router? Or it's the next router that discard my package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not acknowledged within the expected timeout.

See [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17793/what-does-an-asterisk-star-in-traceroute-mean)
for detail.

Comment: The problem is that I can't ping any website, so I want to find out why. It's not that routers continue routing but don't reply, it's definitely some router discard my package, or firewall.

Comment: Can you access website from your browser ?

Comment: If yes, than your router or your ISP is preventing ICMP Traffic of any kind. Call your ISP for guidance.

Comment: No. First there's no browser cause it's a remote server. Second I'm pretty sure I can't access websites.

Comment: Can you access website from the machine from which you are trying to use 'traceroute'.

Comment: or ping from that machine ?

Comment: All operations are done on that remote machine, i.e. the machine I use traceroute.

Comment: Might be a firewall issue. You can't get out of your network, that's why you can't ping, access web, etc. Fix network settings of remote machine. :)